# Projection of a polytope along 4 orthogonal axes

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry

Consider the following problem:

Given an $\mathcal{H}$-polytope $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $4$ orthogonal vectors $v_1, ..., v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^d$, compute the projection of $P$ to the subspace generated by $v_1, ..., v_4$ (and ouput it as an $\mathcal{H}$-polytope).

I know that the problem of computing projections along $k$ orthogonal vectors is NP-hard (if $k$ and $d$ are part of the input), as shown in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.4150.pdf). But does it help if $k$ is a constant? Specifically, does it help if $k \leq 4$? Do we have a polynomial algorithm in this case?

Comment: This is a useless comment, but it *feels* like you must still enumerate the vertices even to project down to 4D. So it may be VE-complete. On the other hand, if you rotate all data so that the $4$ orthog vectors are Cartesian coords, it seems like it should be polynomial.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: How about the case where both $k$ and $d$ are small constants? Do you think this case might be easier?